# How can I remove the duplicate json set from the response in wso2 ei and then desplaiy the result?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Currently I'm getting a response from api like below. How can I remove the duplicate set and show only unique details (For example in the below example {
"text": "P118/2012",
"value": "P118/2012"
},
{
"text": "P365/2023",
"value": "P365/2023"
}) have been repeated twice.I need to have them only once in the response. Thanks

```html
{
    "message": {
        "status": "Success",
        "timestamp": "2023-06-20T16:45:55.6606029+10:00",
        "resultCount": 7,
        "totalCount": 7
    },
    "fields": {
        "ApplicationNumber": {
            "listItems": [
                {
                    "text": "211/1988",
                    "value": "211/1988"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P118/2012",
                    "value": "P118/2012"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P365/2023",
                    "value": "P365/2023"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P1424/2022",
                    "value": "P1424/2022"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P118/2012",
                    "value": "P118/2012"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P365/2023",
                    "value": "P365/2023"
                },
                {
                    "text": "P1424/2021",
                    "value": "P1424/2021"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To remove duplicate objects from the 'listItems' array, you can use JavaScript's Set and the map() function.

Comment: I've tried that but it seems the js doesn't like set() there. I got this error The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Set" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#4) in <Unknown Source> at line number 4
 at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
 at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)

Comment: Then you can use reduce or filter in javascript 
`var uniqueItems = listItems.reduce((unique, item) => {
            var foundItem = unique.find((uniqueItem) => uniqueItem.text === item.text && uniqueItem.value === item.value);
            if (!foundItem) {
                unique.push(item);
            }
            return unique;
        }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but whichever way you implement it, you will still have to reconstruct the message. Here is one way to do this without using the script mediator.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/Duplicates" name="DuplicateAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" type="inline">
                    <Values/>
                </source>
                <target property="values" type="property"/>
            </enrich>
            <foreach expression="//listItems/text" id="123">
                <sequence>
                    <filter regex="true" source="contains($ctx:values, //text/text())">
                        <then/>
                        <else>
                            <enrich>
                                <source clone="true" type="body"/>
                                <target action="child" xpath="$ctx:values"/>
                            </enrich>
                        </else>
                    </filter>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <listItems>$1</listItems>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$ctx:values"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Response**

```json
{
    "listItems": {
        "Values": {
            "text": [
                "211/1988",
                "P118/2012",
                "P365/2023",
                "P1424/2022",
                "P1424/2021"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```